# PHP make subfile of a placeholder file?

Tags: php, repository, repository-pattern

I have the following structure for my site:

`./u/`
`./u/profile.php`
`./u/comics.php`

profile.php is filtered with the viewer's username. For example, the account *Venk* would be `./u/Venk`. I need `comics.php` to somehow be a subfolder of this but I'm not sure how to go about doing so. It should end up looking like this: `./u/Venk/comics`.

How can I get this to work?

*P.s,* I *could* just use AJAX to do this `./u/comics?username=Venk` but that is just ugly and inconsistent and just overall makes my site's theme look messy so I'd much prefer an alternative.

*P.p.s,* Feel free the edit the post to make the title more concise, I wasn't really sure how to word it in basic terminology.

Comment: You can use rewrite rules, are you using apache or nginx?
Post nginx configuration or .htaccess file here

Comment: @whyguy http://prntscr.com/vo15n2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file in root with this content, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

You don't have to keep PHP files inside `u` directory, move `profile.php` and `comics.php` to root as well.

```
RewriteEngine On

# from: /u/{word}/comics
# to: /comics?username={word}
RewriteRule ^u/(\w+)/comics$ /comics.php?username=$1
```

Comment: Think you misunderstood, I don't want to use AJAX, I'd prefer if the from/to were flipped.

Comment: I think you need the comics page to be served in this URL `/u/{word}/comics`
and that `RewriteRule` will do just that. Note: it's not a redirect, apache will get the request in that fancy URL and serve `comics.php`.